# Why does my exit thread not work to stop my while loop?

Tags: python

So these code should take the coordinates I provided, randomize them, and move/click on those coordinates and repeat. I wanted a way to exit the while(true) loop so I got the code for threading and used the key 'n'. It is not working though.

```py
import keyboard
import time
import threading, pyautogui, sys, time, random, keyboard


class main:
    def __init__(self):
        # Create a run variable
        self.run = True

        # Start main thread and the break thread
        self.mainThread = threading.Thread(target=self.main)
        self.breakThread = threading.Thread(target=self.breakThread)

        self.mainThread.start()
        self.breakThread.start()

    def breakThread(self):
        # Check if run = True
        while True and self.run == True:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('n'):
                self.newFunction()

    def main(self):
        pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.01
        # Also check if run = True
        while not keyboard.is_pressed('n') and self.run == True:
            coords = [(327, 213),
                      (313, 309),
                      (307, 420),
                      (439, 420),
                      (561, 413),
                      (560, 320),
                      (428, 322),
                      (324, 198),
                      (437, 203),
                      (780,275)]
            random.shuffle(coords)
            for x in coords:
                pyautogui.moveTo(x[0], x[1], 0.01, pyautogui.easeInOutQuad)
                pyautogui.click()
                time.sleep(0.1)
            # Break like this
            if keyboard.is_pressed('n'):
                break

            time.sleep(0.1)

    def newFunction(self):
        self.run = False

program = main()
```

Comment: in line `while True and self.run == True:` you can skip first `True` and run only `while self.run == True:` to get the same result. You can even write shorter `while self.run:`

Comment: you can define `coords` before `while`-loop

Comment: `keyboard` has `keyboard.add_hotkey('n', self.newFunction)` which doesn't need loop and it doesn't need `threading` because `keyboard` will run it in own loop and in own thread. And this way you can run function `main` also without threading.

Comment: code works for me on Linux

Comment: what means `It is not working`? Do you get error? Show it in question (not in comments). or maybe code exiting at once ? It may need to use `.join()` to wait for end of thread.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, I don't know what is the problem because it works for me on Linux.

But I will show something different. Maybe this will work for you.

`keyboard` has `keyboard.add_hotkey('n', self.newFunction)` which doesn't need `loop` and it doesn't need `threading` because keyboard will run it in own `loop` and in own `thread`. And this way you can run function `main()` also without `threading`.

```
import time
import random
import keyboard
import pyautogui


class Main:  # PEP8: `CamelCaseNames` for classes

    def __init__(self):
        self.run = True

        keyboard.add_hotkey('n', self.stop)

        self.main()

    def main(self):
        pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.01

        coords = [(327, 213),
                  (313, 309),
                  (307, 420),
                  (439, 420),
                  (561, 413),
                  (560, 320),
                  (428, 322),
                  (324, 198),
                  (437, 203),
                  (780, 275)]

        while self.run:
            random.shuffle(coords)

            for x, y in coords:
                pyautogui.moveTo(x, y, 0.01, pyautogui.easeInOutQuad)
                pyautogui.click()
                time.sleep(0.1)
                if not self.run:
                    #break  # exit only `for`-loop (and it will have to check `while self.run`)
                    return  # directly exit function `main()` 

    def stop(self):
        self.run = False

program = Main()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: It works for me when I run it on my windows VM but when I run it on my m1 macbook it does not exit the loop when pushing 'n' which is why I was very confused. I tried yours which is much cleaner than mine (thank you for that) and it still does not exit when I hit n.

Comment: It looks like my mac is not recognizing the keyboard module key presses. I just tested it with a simple script and it never recognized me pressing it

Comment: you may have to ask keyboard's author for this problem. It keeps code on `GitHub` so you could check in [Issues](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/issues) if someone else had this problem. Maybe it needs to set some settings or you have to wait for newer version. For example on Linux I have to run it as root (using `sudo`) and I rather uses module [pynput](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard). You can alse set new issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

you're not exiting the while loop.

To do so just include break after your if

```py
    def breakThread(self):
        # Check if run = True
        while True and self.run == True:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('n'):
                self.run = False
                break
```